# Unusual initialization of class fields within the class declaration C++

Tags: c++, initialization

By chance, I discovered that the construct below works. I did not realize that this is possible.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  public:
    int a;

    //default constructor
    A(): a(-10){}

    A(int _a): a(_a){}

  static A test_1()
  {
    return A{1};
  }
  static A test_2()
  {
    return A{10};
  }
};//class A

class B
{
public:
  const A data;
  const int a = data.a; //How does this work?

public:
  B() = default;

  B(const A& _data):
    data(_data)
  {}
  
  void printStatus() const
  {
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ";"<< std::endl;
  }
};//class B

int main()
{
  B b_default;
  B b_1(A::test_1());
  B b_2(A::test_2());
  b_default.printStatus();
  b_1.printStatus();
  b_2.printStatus();
  return 1;
}
```

The output is

```
a = -10;
a = 1;
a = 10;
```

I thought that initialization within the class declaration is possible only with the values known during the compilation time.

Is it somewhere in standard? Since which version of C++? How does it work internally? Does constructor adds assignment operators behind the scene even for default constructor?

Comment: Are you referring to `const int a = data.a;`?

Comment: what specifically are you surprised about ? Why would it not "work" ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what parts of the code you wonder about? Is it possible to create an even more minimal [mre]? I think you're trying too hard, and mix several things at once which makes both you and the code confusing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346772/how-can-the-synthesized-default-constructor-initialize-already-initialized-class/63346834#63346834

Comment: Yes, all of the above is standard C++. The constructor didn't add any assignment operators. You did. It's right there, in the code above.

Comment: ```const``` members from your ```class B``` are already constructed at compile time with data from: ```_data```

Comment: @ekaeo That's wrong. `_data` isn't usable in constant expressions and even if it was, members aren't constant-initialized (except as part of a constant-initialized containing object), nor is there any static storage duration object that _could_ be constant-initialized.

Comment: `const int a = data.a;` just means "if `a` is not present in a constructor's initializer list, add `a{data.a}` to that constructor's initializer list".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really nothing unusual going on here. When you call a constructor the members are initialized in the order they are declared.

```
class B
{
  const A data;
  const int a = data.a;
  const int b = data.b;
public:
  B(const A& _data):
    data(_data)
  {}
 // ...
```

`data` is initialized first from `_data` because you provide an initializer in the member initializer list of the constructor.

The other two members are initialized from the default initializer (since C++11) because you do not provide an initializer for them in the member initializer list.

Note that initialization is not assignment.

For more details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor.

> I thought that initialization within the class declaration is possible only with the values known during the compilation time.

No thats wrong. The default initializer is used only when the constructor is called to initialize the member. You are not creating an instance at compile time, so there is also no member to be initialized at compile time. Perhaps you confuse this with initialization of `static` members.